# Windows Phone 8 Page Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a problem that I can't really figure out, and I am really desperate now - I've no idea why it's happening:(
So here is the problem: I am writing a kind of Guess that Tune app. The first page is a menu page, that a user can press "Play" button, and he will navigate to a GenreSelectPage where he selects a genre and navigates to a GamePage. I wanted to handle BackButtonPress on GamePage - when a user hits BackButton, he navigates to MainPage, not GenreSelectPage. Here is the code:

```
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        this.player.Pause();
        var result = MessageBox.Show(AppResources.GamePageAlert, "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            //NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            //App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(@"/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            this.player.Play();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

However, I encoountered a big problem here I can't really solve. When I move back to MainMEnu, than go again to GenreSelectPage and choose the same genre, everything is ok - the app navigates to GamePage where there is list of 4 answers. However, if I choose another genre, the listBox at GamePage is populated with 12 or 15 items. On the other hand, when I comment navigation to MainPage and normally go back, everything works alright.
Here is my GenrePage Code:

```
public GenresPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = App.ViewModel.GenreHelper;
    }

    private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.genresListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        this.progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        this.genresListBox.ItemsSource = await App.ViewModel.GenreHelper.GetGenres();
        this.progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        ClearCollections();
    }

    private static void ClearCollections()
    {
        if (App.ViewModel.TracksCollection.Count != 0)
        {
            App.ViewModel.TracksCollection.Clear();
            App.ViewModel.TrackCounter = 0;
        }
        if (App.ViewModel.AnswerCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            App.ViewModel.AnswerCollection.Clear();
        }
    }

    private async void NavigateToPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.genresListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            this.progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            await App.ViewModel.GetSongs();
            await App.ViewModel.GetAnswers();
            this.progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/Views/GamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }     
    }
```

**UPDATE**
On my GamePage I am only assigning DataContext and duration to MediaElement:

```
public partial class GamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public GamePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var trackId = App.ViewModel.TracksCollection[App.ViewModel.TrackCounter].Id;
        var sampleUri = App.ViewModel.GetSampleUri(trackId);
        player.Source = new Uri(sampleUri.AbsoluteUri);
        player.Play();
    }


    private void GetTrackDuration(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var player = (MediaElement)sender;
        if (player.CurrentState == System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            playerSeekBar.Maximum = player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        this.player.Pause();
        var result = MessageBox.Show(AppResources.GamePageAlert, "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            //NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            //App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(@"/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            this.player.Play();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong, I would be really greatful - I am fighting it all day and I have no idea what's causing it.

Thank You very much in advance!!

Comment: are you loading in gameplay page also? because overpopulating might also cause of the pages being called.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood You correctly - I am loading my collections only once.